# Why can't I simulate a right click here? (with Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, right-click

I'm very new to programing so please forgive me if this has an obvious answer and just so you know I tried to write a program that performs a fishing glitch in the game Terraria.
In the last bit of my code [Main Program] I used the function gui.rightClick(). The function itself works but not in the game. I also tried it with the mouse library where I used the function mouse.right_click() and came to the same result so I figured that it has to do something with the game. Can someone tell me why that is and if there is a way around that? It would really help me so thanks in advance!!! :D Oh and if you know how to improve my code please go right ahead and tell me. Thanks again.

```
import pyautogui as gui
import keyboard, _thread, sys, time

# Global variable for shutting down the program
shutDown = False

# Position of disposable stuff in the inventory
item_x, item_y = 279, 233

# Function that tells the main thread to shut down
def pClose():
    global shutDown
    while True:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("alt+c"):
                shutDown = True
                sys.exit()
        except:
            continue

# Function that checks if it's supposed to shut down the main thread
def pQuit(sD):
    if sD == True:
        sys.exit()

# Initializing thread with pClose()
_thread.start_new_thread(pClose,())

# Start Position of the Cursor
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("alt+p"):
            start_x, start_y = gui.position()
            break
    except:
        continue

time.sleep(2)

# Main Program
for i in range(10):
    pQuit(shutDown)
    gui.press("e")
    pQuit(shutDown)
    gui.moveTo(item_x, item_y, duration= 0.25)
    pQuit(shutDown)
    gui.rightClick()
    pQuit(shutDown)
    gui.moveTo(start_x, start_y, duration= 0.25)
    pQuit(shutDown)
    gui.rightClick()
    pQuit(shutDown)
    gui.press("e")
    pQuit(shutDown)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

More Info:
I can't simulate any kind of mouse click with these two libraries in Terraria but with the program SpeedAutoClicker it does (but that's no really helpful)

Answer (score 1):

Okey I found out. The right click is just to fast for the game to recognize.
I have to use something like mouseUp() and mouseDown().... Well it was a simple solution after all! :D